# Building a poker game with shareable c# code base for Windows, Windows RT and Windows Phone

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8

What are my options if I want to target Windows XP and above desktop OS, Windows RT and Windows Phone 8 for a Poker app which includes both a substantial amount of GUI as well as graphics/animations. Would prefer the whole drawing to be hardware accelerated for a smooth experience.

We already have a  C# & WPF based code base that we would like to use as the starting point for a shareable code base. I want suggestions that would allow us to utilize the existing code base which is already modular to a considerable extent. Moving to an entirely different platform is not an option at the moment.

I understand that Windows Phone 8 also supports C# + XAML for development. But is the drawing hardware accelerated?

If I plan to use MonoGame, would it be too tedious to build up the GUI bits?

Comment: XAML drawing on Windows RT is definitely hardware accelerated, and I believe it is on the phone as well. In any case, coming from WPF and going to XAML based platforms, why are you considering *not* using XAML?

Comment: Sure, XAML rendering is hardware accelerated. One thing i think about XAML is that it can be very heavy and inefficient if you just need to draw simple stuff or draw VERY complex stuff fast :)

Answer (score 0):

Monogame is great engine. You can easily achieve resolution independent rendering with it so you can have solid coordinate system for your GUI textures which will nicely fit into virtualy any resolution. It is also quite flexible and cheap (android, iOs) comparing to other engines. The code is highly reusable across the different platforms. The most code differences are in input handling and file management which are usualy specific for different platforms.

The downside of it is that it lacks any editors and handy tools like in Unity engine. It is pure engine and you have to build/gather your own instruments for all the tasks you want to acomplish. So the task of creating the GUI can be tricky if you need to implement some complex stuff such as physics or some effects. But simple animated GUI is not a problem. There are also several GUI libraries with controls for Monogame:

- https://nuclearwinter.codeplex.com/
- https://xnagui.codeplex.com/

PS: For windows you can merge Monogame with WPF but i doubt you can successfuly use XAML interface in monogame for windows. It will likely be pure WPF or pure Monogame.

If you decide to stick with monogame feel free to look for my samples and tools collection at: http://panthernet.ru/forum/index.php?/topic/17-monogamexna-examples-v18/